# Way to keep spaces in Google App Script alert?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace-for-business

`SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('foo       bar')`

When I use this piece of code, it appears as 'foo bar', removing the additional spaces in between. is there a way coerce Google App Script to do otherwise? It appears to only remove additional spaces, which makes sense, but I'd rather have spaces than dashes. If there isn't a way to do it through the UI API, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Just realized the code formatting also removed the extraneous spaces in the question. I'll try to edit it to reflect what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using spaces consider to use non-breaking spaces `\xa0`. The following code uses `String.prototype.replace` and a regular expression to replace all the spaces by non-breaking spaces.

```
function myFunction() {
  const message = 'foo        bar'.replace(/ /g,'\xa0');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks this works! That's a nifty trick I'll keep in mind.